# Using SQL, get ALL information about spatial index, including CELLS_PER_OBJECT and USING GEOGRAPHY_AUTO_GRID

Tags: sql-server, spatial, spatial-index

When I create a spatial index I can specify some extra parameters, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(
    Id bigint not null,
    Polygon geography not null
)
GO


CREATE SPATIAL INDEX IX_Test_Polygon ON dbo.Test
(
    Polygon
)
USING GEOGRAPHY_AUTO_GRID 
WITH (CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 12)
GO
```

If I then go to SSMS and script this index, then the script will contain these `USING GEOGRAPHY_AUTO_GRID` and `WITH (CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 12)`. However, the view `sys.indexes` does not contain this information.

How can I get this information using SQL, not SSMS.

Comment: Try the [spatial index catalog view documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/spatial-data-catalog-views?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @SMor, yes, that's it. Could you, please, put this as an answer. Thanks!